# Changing order of fields and suppressing extra arXiv identifiers

Tags: biblatex

Even though I have come across some examples in changing the order of fields in biblatex, for some reason I cannot change the order of the `pages` and `date` fields. Now the print is

---

L. Maclerran: "Theory Summary: Quark Matter 2006". J.Phys. G34 (2007), 538-592. arXiv:hep-ph/0702004 [hep-ph]

---

What I would like it to be is

---

L. Maclerran: "Theory Summary: Quark Matter 2006". J.Phys. G34, 538-592 (2007), arXiv:hep-ph/0702004

---

The extra identifier problem is only for the pre-2007 e-prints, when the form of the identifier changed.

Here is my relevant and not-so-relevant (in case I have poked some bit that should be left un-poked) biblatex-related code so far (including my failed attempt to change the order of the `date` and `pages` fields):

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
sorting=none,
backend=bibtex,
doi=false,
firstinits=true,
hyperref]{biblatex}


%supress "in" from biblatex
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
%":" instead of "." after author in biblatex
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
% Collaborations correctly with tag "authortype"
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
   \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifuseauthor} and not test {\ifnameundef{author}} }
     {\printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
     {}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
% removes period at the very end of bibliographic record
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
% "p.101"->"101"
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} 

% (year), pages -> pages (year),
\renewbibmacro{date+pages}{%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit*{\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \newunit}
```

The example citation used is straight from InspireHEP:

```
@article{McLerran:2007hz,
      author         = "McLerran, Larry",
      title          = "{Theory Summary: Quark Matter 2006}",
      journal        = "J.Phys.",
      volume         = "G34",
      pages          = "583-592",
      doi            = "10.1088/0954-3899/34/8/S50",
      year           = "2007",
      eprint         = "hep-ph/0702004",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = HEP-PH/0702004;%%",
}
```

I thank you in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Regarding the arXiv problem: Your `.bib` source should read `eprint         = "0702004", eprinttype= "arXiv", eprintclass="hep-ph"` or if you insist `eprint = "0702004", archivePrefix  = "arXiv", primaryClass   = "hep-ph",`. See p. 115 of the [`biblatex` doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Of course, removing the `primaryClass` field from the `.bib` sources dating back to before April 2007 one by one solves the problem. (I still prefer the form to be the correct `hep-ph/0702004`). I was just wondering, if there is an easier way to deal with these cases. :)

Comment: Sorry, yes for pre-2007 you have `eprint = {math/0307200v3},
eprinttype = {arxiv},` that is remove the `primaryClass`. That is the easiest way in that only this will give you a proper `.bib` file (maybe one cook something up with Biber, but to be honest, I'm not a big fan of ad hoc solutions for blatantly wrong `.bib` files.).

Comment: Do you want to change the order of the `pages` and `year` fields only for `@article`s or for everyone?

Comment: Only for `@article`s

Comment: @moewe I use Mendeley to generate a `.bib` file, but for arXiv papers older than 2007, it generates a wrong entry, for example, `eprint = {0508031}, archivePrefix = {arXiv}, primaryClass = {quant-ph}` instead of `eprint = {quant-ph/0508031}, archivePrefix = {arXiv}` without the `primaryClass` field. Any ideas on how I could change his behaviour?

Comment: @Abhinav This seems to be a Mendeley problem. You should complain to the developers about this. There might be a clever Biber sourcemapping solution, but for that you should ask a new question with an MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to change the order for `@article`s is probably to remove the page number from the bib driver (using the [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package)

```
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{note+pages}}
  {}{}{}
```

We then insert the pages into the `journal+issuetitle` macro like so

```
\newbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,firstinits=true,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%supress "in" from biblatex
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
%":" instead of "." after author in biblatex
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
% Collaborations correctly with tag "authortype"
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
   \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifuseauthor} and not test {\ifnameundef{author}} }
     {\printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
     {}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
% removes period at the very end of bibliographic record
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}
% "p.101"->"101"
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} 

% (year), pages -> pages (year),
\renewbibmacro{date+pages}{%
   \printfield{pages}%
   \setunit*{\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \newunit}

\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{note+pages}}
  {}{}{}

\newbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\cite{baez/article,itzhaki,wassenberg}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]