# Beamer: Change bibliography style with biber removing some fields, and getting rid of warnings

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, biber, warnings

It is the first time I am trying to **include the bibliography with biber in a Beamer presentation**, and I am clueless on how to **change the style** and get rid of some fields. I tried with a **custom .bst file** I obtained with **makebst** but **biber** does not seem to understand it...

So here is my **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{hide notes}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Forrest2014,
    author = {Forrest, Alistair R. R. and Kawaji, Hideya and Rehli, Michael and {Kenneth Baillie}, J. and de Hoon, Michiel J. L. and Haberle, Vanja and Lassmann, Timo},
    doi = {10.1038/nature13182},
    issn = {0028-0836},
    journal = {Nature},
    pages = {462--470},
    pmid = {24670764},
    title = {{A promoter-level mammalian expression atlas}},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature13182{\%}5Cnhttp://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nature13182},
    volume = {507},
    year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Singapore}
}
\begin{document}


\section{Frame 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 1}
    Here I want a citation:

    \cite{Forrest2014}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

*Which produces the following:*

[image: a]
[image: b]

What I would like to accomplish is the following:

- First of all, get rid of the following **warnings**:

> Patching footnotes failed.

*and*

> Font shape `OT1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available(Font) Font shape`OT1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead

I also encounter the following one in my full presentation:

> Font shape `EU2/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available(Font) Font shape`EU2/lmr/m/sc' tried instead

Then I want to **customize the citations** in this way:

- "et al" in italics, in both places
- Only initial for first names
- Year at the end
- No "In: "
- No DOI, ISSN, URL or anything like that

The result should be as close as possible to:

Forrest *et al.* 2014

*and*

Forrest ARR *et al.* “A promoter-level mammalian expression atlas”. *Nature* **507**:462–470 (2014).

What do the **warnings** mean and how to get rid of them? I already used **\lmodern**...

How can I customize bibliography with **biber**, when it does not accept **.bst files from makebst**?

Many thanks!

Comment: It would have been easier if you would not mix different questions in one question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing up the duplicates:

> - First of all, get rid of the warnings

The footnote warning is normal as beamer has its own way to deal with footnotes, see [Beamer patching footnotes warning: "Patching footnotes failed. Footnote detection will not work."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202988/beamer-patching-footnotes-warning-patching-footnotes-failed-footnote-detectio)

> - "et al" in italics, in both places

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40999/36296

> - Only initial for first names

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128823/36296

> - Year at the end

changing the order of the fields can be found at [Biblatex: changing the order of entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries) and [Biblatex: changing the order of entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries) and [Changing order of fields and suppressing extra arXiv identifiers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249564/changing-order-of-fields-and-suppressing-extra-arxiv-identifiers) and [Biblatex: Change order of fields (note+pages) for inproceedings/incollection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283781/biblatex-change-order-of-fields-notepages-for-inproceedings-incollection/283799)

> - No "In: "

[Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex)

> - No DOI, ISSN, URL or anything like that

[Biblatex: Get rid of ISSN, URLs and DOIs in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/biblatex-get-rid-of-issn-urls-and-dois-in-references)

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{hide notes}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, doi=false,isbn=false,url=false, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Forrest2014,
    author = {Forrest, Alistair R. R. and Kawaji, Hideya and Rehli, Michael and {Kenneth Baillie}, J. and de Hoon, Michiel J. L. and Haberle, Vanja and Lassmann, Timo},
    doi = {10.1038/nature13182},
    issn = {0028-0836},
    journal = {Nature},
    pages = {462--470},
    pmid = {24670764},
    title = {{A promoter-level mammalian expression atlas}},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature13182{\%}5Cnhttp://www.nature.com/doifinder/10.1038/nature13182},
    volume = {507},
    year = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Singapore}
}
\begin{document}


\section{Frame 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 1}
    Here I want a citation:

    \cite{Forrest2014}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sam! I was starting to figure it out and was going to post an edit... the font warnings seem to have to do with the way DOI, ISSN, etc are printed, so when setting them to false, those warnings go away...

Comment: So as I have it now, the only problem is the footnote warning... Can it be safely ignored?

Comment: @DaniCee To my knowledge: yes

Comment: Sorry I will tend to split up my questions and look deeper into each individual problem before posting...

Comment: in the link you provide for the footnotes warning, they mention it can be solved by changing an .sty file... I use my own beamer theme with my own .sty file, do you know what should be changed in there? Thanks!

Comment: @DaniCee The changes would have to be made in a .sty file part of the biblatex package, nothing to do with your own theme. But why not simply using http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202994/36296 ?

Comment: Yes, it seems it's safe, so I will just silence it then... thanks again